# Using nested for loops in Java 8, to find out given difference

Tags: java, java-8

I have below code where I am using nested for loops and I have some condition that breaks the inner for loop, and this improves the performance of this code.

Assume that the list provided is already sorted. Now I want to find the number of elements whose difference is equal to some value say `k`.

```
public static int getCount(List<Integer> list, int k) {
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < list.size(); j++) {
            if (list.get(j) - list.get(i) > k) {
                break;
            }
            if (list.get(j) - list.get(i) == k) {
                result++;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Now the same logic using Java 8 streams, here to skip inner loop I have used `return` statement, but as the inner loop is not broken the performance is not improved.

```
public static int getCount(List<Integer> list, int k) {
    int[] result = { 0 };
    IntStream.range(0, list.size()).forEach(i -> {
        IntStream.range(i + 1, list.size()).forEach(j -> {
            if (list.get(j) - list.get(i) >= k)
                return;
            if (list.get(j) - list.get(i) == k) {
                result[0]++;
            }
        });
    });
    return result[0];
}
```

Comment: @Alexei Kaigorodov, @Andy Turner, The `marked as duplicate` does not explain about how to do this with nested for loops. Also my logic is about counting such occurrences, the link does not explain that.

Comment: The duplicate makes it quite clear that there is no easy or idiomatic way to break out of `forEach` iteration. In Java 9 you could use `takeWhile`. But even this would be an inefficient way to solve the problem: it's still quadratic, whereas you could do it linearly (but not with streams).

Comment: Same as with your previous question, you are worrying about the tiny improvement of terminating the loop earlier instead of finding an approach with a lower asymptotic cost. If the list is sorted, you can use binary search instead of the inner loop. Or you maintain two indices into the list for an element *e* and its *e+k* position in a single loop.

Comment: @Holger, `Or you maintain two indices into the list for an element e and its e+k position in a single loop. ` Can you please explain what it means? I understand like `e` is an element in the list, so see if `e+k` is also present in the list. Like this, I have to repeat for each element. Looks like what I am thinking is different from your point.

Comment: Start with `index1`, the index of `e` at `0`. Find `index2`, the index of `e+k`, e.g. via `Collections.binarySearch`. Now enter the loop: raise `index1` by one. Since the list is sorted, the new `e` is bigger than the old one, hence, the index of `e + k` must be bigger than the old one too. Raise `index2` until you either, found `e+k` or reached an element bigger than `e+k`. Repeat until `index2` reaches the end of the list. Then, you don’t need to raise `index1` any more as the corresponding `e+k` wouldn’t be in the list. So you’re done. The bigger `k`, the less elements you have to check…

Answer (score 0):

Replace your inner `IntStream.forEach()` with the following and see if it works as expected:

```
IntStream.range(i + 1, list.size())
        .filter(j -> list.get(j) - list.get(i) == k)
        .forEach(j -> result[0]++);
```

Comment: Same issue, here also we are not breaking inner loop, so I am getting performance issue.